# How to generate barcode in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, barcode

I got a small issue about how to display a code generated based on IF condition and HTML element on barcode in Angular 6

so in the code below I want to generate the (L)8257  on the barcode
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbwsg3

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please try and explain the issue, when I visit that StackBlitz I can see a barcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xybduw

I added a `[(ngModel)]="isChecked"` to the checkbox and added a read-only property `barcodeValue` to the typescript.

Comment: It Works. ) ) Thank you, Thomas. I do appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code. I am sure it will help you.

```
<div id="lotarea">
  <div class="lotnumber">


  <div id="CODE">  <span *ngIf="big.checked">L</span> <span #dayOfTheYear></span> </div>

  </div>
  <span class="ddate">{{date | date: 'MMM d, y, HH:m:s'}}</span>


<ng-container *ngIf="true" >
    <div id="content" >

      <ngx-barcode [bc-value]="3123123" [bc-display-value]="true"></ngx-barcode>


  </div>

 </ng-container>
  <br>


</div>
```